# Send Email to external domain asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, email, cross-domain

I'm unable to send any email to an external email address from my ASP.NET webpage.

Below is my code:

```
 Dim oMsg As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()    

        Dim add As New MailAddress("emailaddy@external_address.com")    
        oMsg.From = New MailAddress("something@mydomain.com")
        oMsg.To.Add(add)
        oMsg.Subject = "Your Account Details & Information"
        oMsg.Body = "my body text"
        oMsg.IsBodyHtml = True

        Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("local_smtp_server", 25)
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

        smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("auser@mydomain.com", "mypassword")
        smtp.Send(oMsg)
```

is there anything I am missing? If I send to a local email it will work just fine.
 Is there something that I need to change on the MS Exchange Server?

Any code samples can be given in C# as well...

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Any chance it's getting blocked by a service? Maybe you need the port opened or the protocol unblocked?

Comment: @BrianWebster I'm not getting any errors...

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure because I have access to the exchange server, and when I try to send the email from the application it doesn't show up in the queue

Comment: You may try sending on a port other than 25. It is commonly blocked

Comment: If I change the port to another number, it doesn't work at all. @BrianWebster Do you know if I need to change anything on the Exchange server for my user?

Comment: Not sure, sorry. Just double check that port 25 is not blocked on the machine's firewall or any firewalls beyond the machine